# A problem with array

Tags: modifiers

So I have an object that I mirrored, and then I created an empty cube, the Origin point of the cube and the origin point of this object is in the same position, in the middle of the 3D cursor, but the problem is when I try to array this subject by empty cube, it gives me a very strange result.[image] Here is the video with the time code of how it is supposed to be https://youtube.com/clip/Ugkxers6YUajXyxG3KgqTjMgX9B82WUd8hTr

And I will leave a picture of what I have,  (I turned the face orientation so it is visible that all the normals set correctly)
Would appreciate the help!

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply rotation and scale and that should be ok. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
<kbd>A</kbd> then "rotation & scale".

You'll eventually need to change the mirror modifier axis after that.

[image]

Comment: It worked, thank you!